# Z3py: parse_smt2_file raises Exception

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm trying to parse an `.smt2` file (which gives an answer without a problem if I just run it over z3) in my python file

```
ctx = Context()
s = Solver(ctx=ctx)
f = parse_smt2_file("./Encodings/foo.smt2", ctx=ctx)
s.add(f)
```

and I get the following problem:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       f = z3.parse_smt2_file("./ex.smt2", ctx=ctx)   File "X/Applications/z3-4.3.3.376614a7822d-x64-osx-10.9.5/bin/z3.py", line
>   7305, in parse_smt2_file
>       return _to_expr_ref(Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(ctx.ref(), f, ssz, snames, ssorts, dsz, dnames, ddecls), ctx)   File
>   "X/Applications/z3-4.3.3.376614a7822d-x64-osx-10.9.5/bin/z3core.py",
>   line 2947, in Z3_parse_smtlib2_file
>       raise Z3Exception(lib().Z3_get_error_msg_ex(a0, err)) Z3Exception: parser error

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide the smt2 file? It's probably something related to the logic declaration and/or function name clashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file finished by

```
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I removed this lines and it worked

Comment: You can accept your own answer. Please do so, this will mark the question as having been answered.